# Send command line argument/flag like '--relaxed-security' to saucelabs while initiating an appium session

Tags: appium, saucelabs

I want to be able to execute certain adb shell commands on real devices in saucelabs.

I learned from https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/2019/02/13/Enhance+your+Appium+tests+on+emulators+with+ADB+commands that I can make use of '--relaxed-security' flag while initiating an appium session on saucelabs to execute adb shell commands.

While it is easier to pass command line arguments while starting appium on local machines, I'm not sure how to include the flag while connecting to saucelabs.

This is how I'm initiating a session on saucelabs :

```
desired_capabilities = {
    "deviceName": "xxx",
    "platformName": "xx",
    "platformVersion": "xx",
    "bundleId": "xxx",
    "automationName": "uiautomator2", 
    "testobject_api_key" : "xxx"
}
driver = webdriver.Remote("https://us1-manual.app.testobject.com/wd/hub", desired_capabilities)
```

Answer (score 1):

This has not been enabled in the Real Device Cloud of Sauce Labs so it will not work in this case

**Update 20210825:**

We've discussed the feature "*ADB support for Android Real Devices*" with our Product Team and they will investigate this from a technical perspective to see if this will be feasible. I'll keep you posted

Comment: Thank you @wswebcreation. I got around the problem by dynamically selecting certain values in my test scripts.

Comment: @MaheshS Could you please suggest me the workaround for this problem. I'm running through the same, I was able to execute it locally using the server flag --relaxed-security. 
However, it doesn't seem to be working with sauce. Thanks!!

Comment: I've updated my comment above. Currently you CAN NOT use ADB commands with Android real devices, but we're looking into it

Comment: Thank you for the update @wswebcreation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is enabled by default, you can double check your project to have `Instrumentation` option enabled.

Since it is a server flag, you can't pass it from client side and I don't see a way to do it via capability.

Try to run adb command and if it won't work - ask their support.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you're right. It is not possible via capabilities. I worked around the problem by implementing certain things in my test script.

Comment: @MaheshS Could you please let me know, what changes have you implemented in the test script as a part of this?

Comment: @KishoreMohanavelu I wanted to enable location services in assigned iPhones before starting my test executions. I'm doing this via my script. Since I'm using a regular expression for device name value, a different device may or may not get assigned to each of my test executions from Saucelabs.

Comment: @MaheshS could you add the script here or in your question please. This will help us understand what the script is exactly doing.